# setting the pathname of the trigger_file in postgres

Tags: postgresql, failover

when setting the trigger_file name in the Postgres `recovery.conf` file, when I use

```
trigger_file = '$PGDATA/failover_file'
```

and then `touch $PGDATA/failover_file`, the failover is not working

but when I use the full path name of

```
trigger_file = '/opt/rh/postgresql92/root/var/lib/pgsql/data/failover_file'
```

and then `touch $PGDATA/failover_file`, the failover works ok

does anyone know when the use of the environment variable in the trigger_file stops the failover from working?

thanks
Dave

Comment: I don't think environment variables are expanded in `postgresql.conf` or `recovery.conf` settings. What gave you the idea that they would be? If there's documentation that says that then it needs to be fixed, so please show a link.

Comment: I have used the $PGDATA variable in the recovery.conf file as part of the restore_command setting. It quiet happily expands the variables there but not in the trigger_file. I haven't read anywhere where it says it does or does not expand the variables in these files, but I thought it would be consistent.

Comment: That's because `recovery_command` is a shell command, so you can use shell metacharacters like `$variable` there. To PostgreSQL it's just a text string, but the shell interprets it when PostgreSQL runs the command, and it sees the `PGDATA` env var that's set by PostgreSQL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, environment variables are not parsed or recognized in any way in `recovery.conf`.

`restore_command` is a special case because postgres executes it with the C `system()` function, described by `man 3 system` as:

```
   system()  executes a command specified in command by calling /bin/sh -c
   command, and returns after the command has been completed.
```

So in fact it is that shell to which `restore_command` is passed which expands environment variables, not postgres.

On the other hand, no shell is involved in `trigger_file`, so no variable expansion occurs.